# Is the chat link gone?

Tags: discussion, chat, footer

How to go to chat, is the link gone or am I not finding it? I can't seem to find the link to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ that was located in the footer. And why hide it?

Comment: It is in the McDonalds menu (hamburger) in the topbar at the far right. You see some screenshots [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345218/visually-distinguish-help-from-chat-in-multi-collider)

Comment: @rene I figured that,  Someone inevitably would have asked, just didn't find it, so I just asked, it's  meta after all, you could close it

Comment: Maybe someone could update the Help page that still says you can find it in the footer of every page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms